# Unable to deploy application to Raspberry Pi 3, Windows 10 IoT Core

Tags: arm, uwp, raspberry-pi3, windows-iot-core-10

I'm receiving the following error when attempting to deploy my `UWP` application to my connected **Raspberry Pi 3, Model B**. I am running *Windows 10 IoT Core (Version: 10.0.14393.0)* on my Pi and *Windows 10 Insider Preview Build 10586* on my development box.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Mirror, Configuration: Debug ARM ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.
1>  Mirror -> C:\Users\david.pine\Source\Repos\Mirror\Mirror\bin\ARM\Debug\Mirror.exe
2>------ Deploy started: Project: Mirror, Configuration: Debug ARM ------
2>Error: Field not found: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ImmersiveProjectServices.BootstrapperOperationPackage.StandardCollectorCpuAgent'.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

**Update**

[Here is the `.csproj`](https://github.com/IEvangelist/Mirror/blob/master/Mirror/Mirror.csproj) that was mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Have you tried with the build log verbosity set to detailed ? Does it say anything usefull ? You may found the name of the culprit dependency.

Comment: @Vincent looking into that now...

Comment: Did you check your .csproj file and see what the values for `TargetPlatformVersion` and `TargetPlatformMinVersion` are?

Comment: Just a FYI, your projects deploys/runs successfully on my RP2.

Comment: @Jackie that is totally saddening, I wish I could get it to work for me. 

Comment: Yeah, not sure if this helps, but I'm having VS2015 update 3, windows IoT 10.0.14376.

Comment: Did you try to get the build log verbosity up? Maybe your dependencies have conflicting 'sub-dependencies'? Check how to build via console: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171470.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @Jackie can you please share in detail what exactly you did to deploy and run it?

Comment: @DavidPine, I just pulled your Mirror repo, builds deploys it to my RP2 with OS 10.0.14376. I'll get an RP3 with 10.0.14393.0 for testing shortly.

Comment: @Jackie Thanks!  I might have found something here. My VS 2015 had a deprecated Universal Windows SDK, the one I'm installing now is 10.0.14393.0 which sounds like the golden ticket!

Comment: @DavidPine, oh, I'm using VS2015 with update 3.

Comment: @DavidPine, FYI, deploying to RP3 with 10.0.14393.0 also works fine.

Comment: @DavidPine, Any luck?

Comment: @DavidPine Awesome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I had a dated *Universal Windows Development SDK*, build `10586`. I upgraded to build `14393` -- which ironically matches the OS version of the installed **Windows 10 IoT Core** on my **Raspberry Pi 3**.

I then set the target framework version and it works:

[image]

Comment: Where do you get the UWP SDK from? I can only find links to Visual Studio downloads.

Comment: The **UWP SDK** was a _VS 2015_ install opt-in option. Not sure how to get it outside of the installer?

Comment: I decided to reinstall my VS2015 as it seemed generally broken. After reinstall, even though I selected UWP tools 10.0.14393 during setup, it tells me that there's an "Update Required" and refuses to open my projects. The good thing to come out of this is that I found this page: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive

Answer (score 0):

Please check you referenced DLL and nuget package dll version.you might find duplicate but different version dll over there.Otherwise please reinstall nuget packages and then rebuild the solution.